# Push DVCS repository to master without needing codebase

Tags: language-agnostic, version-control, dvcs, vpn

To work on a client's staging environment I have to connect through a VPN which locks all normal network traffic and prevents any connection to the Internet.

This would immediately prevent any of the "normal" VCS solutions from being used as it's not possible to gain access to the server. A solution to this would be to create a DVCS repository (git?) locally and then push changes to the master, as and when needed. There is one flaw in this plan.

**The entire codebase is around 14GB**. To download all of this over the internet would take some time, especially when I'm likely to be working on 3 or 4 different machines in each case. This seems silly and overkill for a DVCS.

**TL;DR**
*Can any DVCS solution allow you to push to a master server/repo without needing the codebase*? Bad example: copy the .git folder (not the 14GB codebase) to another directory and push this to the master once disconnected from the VPN.

Comment: Codebase of 14GB without any subprojects (it can't be splitted)? I don't think there are dvcs that really works with partial history (that's what you are looking for).

Comment: Due to the locked down nature of the VPN, it's been difficult to get any kind of version control implemented on the project apart from a rudimentary daily, weekly and monthly back-up process from the client. It could be possible to turn it into sub-projects but the largest of these would stack up around the 4GB mark. There is no previous vcs history for this codebase, just -- luckily? -- an amazing set of documentation that we've been religious about updating.

Comment: So the problem is transferring the data from the clients (which already have the codebase) to the server? Am I right?

Some points that may help you: a hg repo, or a **repacked** git repo might be much smaller than 14GB (in the hg case it's gzipped, git probably does something similar with some delta compression). Then you only need to push the repo to the server once, after that it will only be deltas which are a lot smaller.

Comment: @tonfa you are correct in that the issue is transferring the codebase (on VPN) to the server (on the Internet).

Comment: I suggest you to try putting the files into a hg and a git repo and measure the .hg and .git directories size. Maybe you'll have a nice surprise.

Comment: If you'd like to thoroughly go through the steps you outlined above, It's likely I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any DVCS that works without somehow transferring the codebase to the remote server.

**But** modern DVCS's like git or mercurial are able to compress the initial codebase. After creating the initial repository on the client, you often have the nice surprise that the `.hg` or `.git` directory is much smaller than the working directory that was added (for git you'll need to repack the repo first to see a gain in space).

For an even smaller transfer, the [bundle feature](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CreateBundleOfAllChanges) of mercurial could be used (it uses bz2 instead of zlib).